# В каком месте меняется коллекция?

Tags: c#, коллекции

Класс ItemSet реализует словарь типа Dictionary, int>. Надо объединить строку из первого словаря со вторым словарем. При запуске выдается ошибка "Коллекция была изменена, невозможно выполнить операцию перечисления". С чем связано?

```
        public ItemSet UnionOfItemSet(ItemSet firstItemSet, ItemSet secondItemSet)
    {
        ItemSet resItemSet = new ItemSet();


        resItemSet = firstItemSet; //формируется множество, сначала состоящее из первого набора

        foreach(var item in firstItemSet)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in secondItemSet)
            {
                if (item.Key != item2.Key)
                {
                    var tempList = item.Key.Union(item2.Key).ToList();

                    resItemSet.Add(tempList, Support(item.Key, item2.Key));
                }                   
            }
        }

        return resItemSet;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Связано с тем, что переменные `resItemSet` и `firstItemSet` ссылаются на один и тот же объект.

```
ItemSet resItemSet = new ItemSet();
foreach(var item in firstItemSet)
  resItemSet.Add(item, ???);

foreach(var item in firstItemSet)
{
  ...
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @LikaBarken Пожалуйста. Успехов!